# Resize chrome browser window

Tags: html, css, django, google-chrome, media-queries

The minimum width of google chrome can be only 500 pixels but I want it to be reduced to 320 pixels, for that what should I do or is there any extension or something else for that??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Select "toggle device toolbar" (ctrl + shift + M) in Chrome's dev tools

[image]

2. Select "responsive" device
3. Set the width of your choice

[image]